# Compiler issue with pure virtual class and inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

There is a compiler issue that I am facing. The code that I want to compile is as follows

```
#include <iostream>

class IA
{
    public:
    virtual void f1() = 0;
};

class A
{
    public:
    virtual void f1() { std::cout << "in A::f1" <<std::endl; }
};

class IB : public IA
{
    public:
    virtual void f3() = 0;
};

class B : public A, public IB
{
    public:
 //   virtual void f1() { std::cout << "in B::f1" <<std::endl; }
    virtual void f3() { std::cout << "in f3" <<std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    IB* b =  new B();
    b->f1();
    b->f3();
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

Here, If I uncomment B::f1 things workout fine. The current code gives the following compiler error.

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:32:20: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘B’
     IB* b =  new B();
                    ^
source_file.cpp:23:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘B’:
 class B : public A, public IB
       ^
source_file.cpp:8:18: note:     virtual void IA::f1()
     virtual void f1() = 0;
```

The intent here is that the interface, IA, would be defined in the public headers of the library. The implementation class, A, would be done in the source code. All other classes would make use of this base class(A) to implement the publicly exposed abstract interface. Is this possible?

Comment: `A::f1` doesn't override anything.

Comment: `A` does not inheret from `IA` so no one ever implements the virtual function `IA::f1()`. The function `A::f1()` is a different function entirely.

Comment: It's possible but A must implement IA otherwise you'll have A::f1() and IA::f1() there.

Comment: Thanks for you replies. I was looking at a RefCounter object has the declaration as a pure interface and the implementation that does not derive from the interface. The implementation could be used in all the implementation of interfaces that derive from the RefCounter base interface. Now, I know it may not be possible to do it through inheritance. Though, i may achieve the same using containment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
class A
```

to

```
class A : public IA
```

But it's not enough, as now you get multiple instances of `IA` in `B`. So you have to make the inheritance virtual:

```
class A : virtual public IA {...};
class IB : virtual public IA {...};
```

**UPDATE** But is there a real reason for `IB` to be inherited from `IA`? If no, drop it, and you won't need virtual inheritance:

```
class A : public IA {...};
class IB {...};

int main()
{
    IB* b =  new B();
    // b->f1(); -  You can't do it now, but do you really need to?
    b->f3();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since it doesn't add anything to this. +1 but I still don't like this design though

Comment: @MarcoA., Yours did have something to add. A suggestion to change the design.

Comment: As the interface does not have any data-members, avoiding virtual inheritance would be preferable.

Comment: @chris A comment suits better ;)

Comment: @MarcoA. Added to answer my considerations on design :)